# Vite devServer with external api call locally

Tags: axios, vite, react-query

Im trying to create a simple app and use tansStack, axios, react and vite.
All GET requests work, but as soon as I do a POST or DELETE it fails do to CORS.
The api I'm calling has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` and as I understand it with POST, PUT, DELETE you need to specifiy the response origin on the local dev server if [wildcard is set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#the_http_response_headers) in the response.

I have tried to turn of CORS with setting cors to false in the vite.config and adding allowed origins to the config object.
I have also tried adding different headers to the axios call.

If I use ThunderClient (similar to PostMan) both the POST and DELETE work.

Could I get some help on witch direction I should go from here.

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    open: '/index.html',
    cors: false
  },
})
```

/

```
 const { mutate } = useMutation({
            mutationFn: async (newStation: Station): Promise<Station> => {
                return await axios.post(
                    `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/stations?appid=API_KEY`,
                    newStation,
                    {
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                    }
                );
            },
            onSuccess: (data) => {
                queryClient.setQueryData(['weatherStations', data.id], data);
                queryClient.invalidateQueries(['weatherStations'], { exact: true });
            },
        });
```

[image]

**Edit:**

To anyone see this and have the same issue.
I solved this after many hours of searching.
In the vite.config add a proxy like this:

```
proxy: {
  "/weather/api": {
    target: "http://api.openweathermap.org/",
    changeOrigin: true,
    rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/weather\/api/,''),
  }
}
```

Then when you use axios to do the call

```
await axios.delete(`api/data/3.0/stations/${id}?appid=API_KEY`, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            });
```

Vite devserver will replace api with above proxy. Because CORS error is between client->server and not server->server.